# What's the process to replace 'WHERE...IN' clauses in Artifactory? Those are terrible in enterprise-size installations

Tags: sql, artifactory

My client is a huge user of Artifactory, with thousands of users.

There are places in the Artifactory codebase that are using 'WHERE ... IN' SQL clauses, that can really play havoc with the servers, as they are linear searches.  We've had outages, caused by simple web page views.

I'd like to replace those with 'create table(...);insert into ...;select ... inner join on table; drop table', or at least make a few patches for pull requests into the mainline build.

Can anyone recommend a process for doing this ?  It might be tricky because of all the different SQL databases that are supported.

Comment: WHERE..IN isn't inherently slow. Could this be rbar issues or missing indexes?

Comment: It's a linear search, so it's slow when there are hundreds of elements...  It was identified and isolated as the cause.